# Nginx proxy_pass to a variable url

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx. As I know, we can configure proxy_pass url in nginx.conf like:

```
location /test
{
     proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:10000;
}
```

But now, I need to proxy_pass to a variable url, we could get this url in http request header or request body(for example).

How could I implement this? Thanks for any help!

EDIT 1(explain my question):

There is a http request with a param named "redirectUrl" in its header send to Nginx, I just want Nginx modify this http request header and then send this request to the redirectUrl. Because the redirectUrl is a variable, so I guess "proxy_pass $request" can implement this, but I don't know how. Who can give me a hint or is there any documentation?

EDIT 2：

I tried ngx_lua :

```
location /apiproxytest {

    set_by_lua $redirectURL '
            return ngx.req.get_headers()["Host"]
    ';

    header_filter_by_lua '
             ngx.header["RedirectURL"] = nil;
             ngx.header["Host"] = nil;
    ';

    echo "1:" $redirectURL;

    set_by_lua $redirectURL2 '
            return ngx.req.get_headers()["Host"]
    ';

    echo "2:" $redirectURL2;

    #proxy_pass $redirectURL;
}
```

I found that echo 1 and echo 2 were the same, as ngx.header.HEADER explains, ngx.header["Host"] = nil is supposed to remove Host in http request header. Why echo "2:" $redirectURL2 can also print the value of Host?

Comment: Have you read documentation? http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks for your help, I had read the documentation, but it only tell me can, there is no how. Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ngx_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule).

Get `redirectUrl` from `ngx.req.get_headers` in `set_by_lua`, then set to something like `$redirectURL`, finally `proxy_pass $redirectURL`.

Append for Edit 2:

> Why echo 1 and echo 2 were the same?

This is caused by Nginx [Phases](http://wiki.nginx.org/Phases)

`set` or `set_by_lua` is working at `rewrite` phase, `echo` is working at `content` phase, `header_filter_by_lua` is working at `output-header-filter` phase ([doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#header_filter_by_lua)), which is behind content.

Your config is worked like this:

`set_by_lua` -> `set_by_lua` -> `echo 1` -> `echo 2` -> `header_filter_by_lua`.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my new question of using ngx_lua. Please hlep me~

Comment: @SomnusLee I append my answer, wish to help you.